# Laravel dompdf blank pdf

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, dompdf, laravel-6

I'm using laravel-dompdf to generate PDF reports for my app. I had used this in the same app and it's working fine... what whit this model it's generating a blank PDF.

The query is returning data, so that isn't the problem... my code:

```
public function serviceReport(Request $request){
    $title = 'Servicio';

    $meta = [ 
        'N°' => '1'
    ];

    $query = Service::query();

    $query->select(\DB::raw('services.id as serviceid'), \DB::raw('customers.name as customername'))
        ->leftJoin('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'services.id_customers')
        ->where('services.id', '=', '1')
        ->get();

    $columns = [
        'Servicio' => 'serviceid',
        'Cliente' => 'customername'
    ];

    return PdfReport::of($title, $meta, $query, $columns)
    ->limit(20)
    ->download('filename');
}
```

my vuejs function:

```
getReport(){
    var name = 'Reporte Servicio.pdf';
    this.service.post('/api/service/report', {responseType: 'blob'})
    .then((response) => {

        var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));

        var fileLink = document.createElement('a');

        fileLink.href = fileURL;

        fileLink.setAttribute('download', name);

        document.body.appendChild(fileLink);

        fileLink.click();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
},
```

PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is vForm. I have changed to a normal axios request and started to work.